# How to set the java.library.path in intelliJ Idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-native-interface, resin

Could anyone please help how do I solve this error:

```
Native code library failed to load.
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no ts-jni in java.library.path
```

I am using IDEA IDE as a first time, and have been using Resin_4.0.37 as a server to test my work. 
As soon as I start my lcoal server in debug mode it stays for approximately 1-2 mins and then suddenly it drops down and get disconnected by giving me the above error.

I have set my Windows environmental variable correctly; and have also did the following in my IDE intelliJ:

```
 FILE->Project Structure->set Global Libraries->a. Java path and b. Resin library path.
```

Can any one please suggest me, what am I doing wrong and how do I set native library in intelliJ IDEA to solve the mentioned error.

Any help would be appreciated. Also do correct me if I am doing something wrong.

Thanks!

Answer (score 84, accepted):

If you run your program from IntelliJ then you can set the `java.library.path` in the `VM options` input field in the `Run/Debug Configurations` dialog.

[image]

Example:

`-Djava.library.path="C:\path\to\where\the\jni\lib\is"`

Comment: My project has many classes with main method. Is there any way to set that for the whole project?

Comment: @SriHarshaChilakapati, you can edit 'Defaults->Application->VM Options' to get what you want. After defining desired VM option in Defaults, every new run in the project will be created with that VM option.

Comment: what should we do If we need more than one library?                                  -Djava.library.path="C:\qtjambi-4.8.6\lib,C:\qtjambi-4.8.6\bin" is legal?

Comment: @gurpinars On Windows I think you should separate with a semicolon ; and not a comma ,

Comment: FYI: with intellij 2017 -  I have a large project where the JNI dlls are built from an external script that outputs the .dlls into a directory relative to the project root and I had to go into the MyRunConfig.xml file and manually edit it to put the library path into a directory relative to the project root, using "&quot;$PROJECT_DIR$/../build/bin&quot;"

Is there a way to use the intellj UI to specify that the path is realtive and should not be expanded when the .xml is saved ?

Comment: This only works if the DLL does not need other DLL. In my case, my `JNI` DLL needs another `DLL` .

Comment: Thanks a lot the answer really helped