# Wacom Integration into java

Tags: java, sdk, integration, wacom

I just got a signature pad from wacom, the STU 430 and I want to integrate into my Java application.

I downloaded the SDK signature, installed it and then I installed the samples to try it but there's a problem with that.

I can't execute any code so I can't start developing because of the library of the device, let me show u.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I tried to put the library into classes at the package com.wacom.sdk.sample but then there's another Error like: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.wacom.sdk.sample.TestSigCapt`.

How can I solve this error? / How can I integrate this device?

Comment: Which SDK version do you use? What is your IDE? Can you show us the source code where exception occurs?

Comment: Im using Signature-SDK-Windows-3.20.4, IDE: IntelliJ. There's all the code, i have the class there but cant load it, so i just can't access the methods or do any kind of test. @Bsquare

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually fixed, just updated windows. The problem was my version of windows 7 was not supporting external signatures.

Answer (score 2):

**First of all, you need to install all the components on the machine as the documentation states** (I was doing this with a linux machine before). Follow the doccumentation:

On Linux:

- Linux-STU-SDK-Guide.pdf

On Windows:

- STU-SDK Getting Started.pdf     - Getting started guide
- STU-SDK Redistribution.pdf      - Deployment guide
- STU-SigCaptX-Guide.pdf          - Cross browser guide

If I can recall correctly you need to install drivers and different connectors to be able to use the provided examples. For further information and downloads of the referenced documents and SDK-s please visit: https://developer.wacom.com

**After the necessary component installation (and documentation read) you can proceed to the testing**, the part where you have your exception: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException`. This means (in most of the cases) that your classpath (or modulepath) does not contain the necessary `.jar` files which has the `.class` files necessary to run your program. To fix this there are multiple options:

- you can specify `-cp`
- you can alter the `MANIFEST.MF` according to the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html)

Either way your application should start if you follow the documentation and setup your project accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, so which is the most efficient way to do it? "java -cp mypath\flsx.jar TestSigCapt.java" or the manifest one.

Comment: I'd prefer the MANIFEST.MF way as it is a "configure once and never bother again".

Comment: So then how can i modify the manifest.mf of my flsx.jar and what i need to include, following the documentation it seems i need to add a Class-Path: ....jar

Comment: Class-Path: jar1-name jar2-name directory-name/jar3-name

Answer (score 1):

According to your exception message, this question/answer might solve it:

[How to set the java.library.path in intelliJ Idea](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19308010/592355)

...and when run outside intelliJ, ensure the (system/runtime/..) property `java.library.path` is set and points to a location of flsx.jar.

("A million ways" to set java properties: [setting system property](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5189914/592355))

And to "put the cart before the horse": 
Grab the output of `System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.library.path"))` (It should not be blank by default..os, jvm *and runtime* dependant), and copy your jar to (one of) the locations. ;)