# intellij idea build java aplication finished with non-zero exit value 1

Tags: java, intellij-idea

and so on when i run java application in my project
I have an error (code below)

```
    > Task :Start.main()
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no lwjgl64 in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1860)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:871)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1124)
    at org.lwjgl.Sys$1.run(Sys.java:72)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.lwjgl.Sys.doLoadLibrary(Sys.java:66)
    at org.lwjgl.Sys.loadLibrary(Sys.java:87)
    at org.lwjgl.Sys.<clinit>(Sys.java:117)
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.getSystemTime(Minecraft.java:2837)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(Main.java:37)
    at Start.main(Start.java:7)

> Task :Start.main() FAILED

Execution failed for task ':Start.main()'.
> Process 'command 'C:/Users/kostia_admin/.jdks/corretto-1.8.0_332/bin/java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

recreating the project does not help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Errors like `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError` arise when (at runtime) the JVM cannot link to an external native library. In your case, you try to link to a library named `lwjgl64`.

If this library exists, you should point to its directory (at runtime, also) using the `-Djava.library.path=DIR` system property. All main IDEs (Intellijdea, Eclipse etc) provide ways to set this option. For Intelijdea specifically see this [relevant question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19308010/how-to-set-the-java-library-path-in-intellij-idea)

Comment: -Djava.library.path="path to lwjgl64"?

Comment: no, path to directory containing the library

Comment: i watched the whole drive c but i didn't find lwjgl64 / lwjgl
in C: \ Program Files \ Java\ only folders jdk-18.0.1.1 and jre1.8.0_333

Comment: It doesnt have to be inside JDK/JRE folders. Has this program ever run (outside of your IDE)? If it did, it must somehow have located the library to link with. Since you are on Windows, search for a file called `lwjgl64.dll`

Comment: where can i download lwjgl.dll / lwjgl64.dll file? 
because there is no such file on the computer

Comment: i suppose it is part of [LWLGL project](https://www.lwjgl.org)

Comment: @Snaks, was the problem resolved? If yes, please mark the answer as accepted