# no SimpleITKJava in java.library.path with intellij

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, java-native-interface, simpleitk

i am trying to use simpleitk with java.
already setup pom.xml and maven works with no error or warning.
i can even import simpleitk in my scripts and run without problems.

when trying to make something a little bit more complex, i bumped into:

java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no SimpleITKJava in java.library.path

searching for a solution i find:

https://itk.org/Wiki/SimpleITK/GettingStarted/A_visual_guide_to_SimpleITK_in_Java

but the example uses eclipse, and i'm unable to "set the *Native library location" in intellij.
searching, i find *[How to set the java.library.path in intelliJ Idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19308010/how-to-set-the-java-library-path-in-intellij-idea). But cant find this 'VM option', i think it is too old.
i search a lot and tried other things but got no results.

Where do i find the *JNI? Is it supposed to be like 'SimpleITK-0.9.0.jar'? Because i find this on a random maven repository and tried to paste the path everywhere such as:

enrivonrment variables path
file/Project Structure/Modules/Dependencies
file/Project Structure/Libraries
file/Project Structure/Artifacts

but all with no success.*

Comment: `But cant find this 'VM option', i think it is too old.` it is hidden by default in newer versions of IntelliJ. You can make it visible under "Modify options" in the top right of the "Run/Debug Configuration" dialogue